# "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" when running a RandomizedSearchCV with scipy distributions

Tags: python, scipy, integer-overflow, grid-search

I want to run the following `RandomizedSearch`:

```py
from scipy.stats import reciprocal, uniform

tree_reg = DecisionTreeRegressor()

param_grid = {
    "max_depth": np.arange(1, 12, 1),
    "min_samples_leaf": np.arange(2, 2259, 10),
    "min_samples_split": np.arange(2, 2259, 2),
    "max_leaf_nodes": np.arange(2, 2259, 2),
    "max_features": np.arange(2, len(features))
    }

rnd_search_tree = RandomizedSearchCV(tree_reg, param_grid,cv=cv_split, n_iter=10000,
                                    scoring=['neg_root_mean_squared_error', 'r2'], refit='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                                    return_train_score=True, verbose=2)

rnd_search_tree.fit(dataset_prepared_stand, dataset_labels)
```

Where 2259 is the number of data points I have. However, I get the following error:

```py
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-809-76074980f31c> in <module>
     13                                     return_train_score=True, verbose=2)
     14 
---> 15 rnd_search_tree.fit(dataset_prepared_stand, dataset_labels)

~\anaconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

~\anaconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    734                 return results
    735 
--> 736             self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
    737 
    738         # For multi-metric evaluation, store the best_index_, best_params_ and

~\anaconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in _run_search(self, evaluate_candidates)
   1529         evaluate_candidates(ParameterSampler(
   1530             self.param_distributions, self.n_iter,
-> 1531             random_state=self.random_state))

~\anaconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in evaluate_candidates(candidate_params)
    698 
    699             def evaluate_candidates(candidate_params):
--> 700                 candidate_params = list(candidate_params)
    701                 n_candidates = len(candidate_params)
    702 

~\anaconda3\envs\data_analysis\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in __iter__(self)
    283                 n_iter = grid_size
    284             for i in sample_without_replacement(grid_size, n_iter,
--> 285                                                 random_state=rng):
    286                 yield param_grid[i]
    287 

sklearn\utils\_random.pyx in sklearn.utils._random.sample_without_replacement()

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

I do not get it if I'm taking away even just one of the parameters to search over (or if I reduce the step of the range to 1000 for example). Is there a way to solve it passing all the values I'd like to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see an alternative to dropping `RandomizedSearchCV`. Internally `RandomSearchCV` calls `sample_without_replacement` to sample from your feature space. When your feature space is larger than C's `long` size, scikit-learn's `sample_without_replacement` simply breaks down.

Luckily, random search kind of sucks anyway. Check out [`optuna`](https://optuna.org/#code_examples) as an alternative. It is way smarter about where in your feature space to spend time evaluating (paying more attention to high-performing areas), and does not require you to limit your feature space precision beforehand (that is, you can omit the step size). More generally, check out the field of AutoML.

If you insist on random search however, you'll have to find another implementation. Actually, `optuna` also [supports a random sampler](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/samplers.html#module-optuna.samplers).

Comment: If I'm interpreting the traceback correctly (it uses backslashes as directory separators) the OP is on Windows. If they switched to 64 bit Linux, `long` would be 64 bits, not 32, and the range of legal values would dramatically increase. Kind of an extreme solution, but worth noting.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No it wouldn't 'dramatically increase'. Feature spaces increase exponentially in size with the number of features, and thus going from 32-bits to 64-bits effectively only allows you to only double the number of features you wish to optimize over before you run into the exact same problem.

Comment: I'll trust you on that, and that doubling the number of features might be a common desire. Even so, doubling the number of features sounds like a non-trivial benefit. You have an exponential increase in problem space size that matches the exponential increase in capacity of `long`, so it's a linear gain in "number of features supported", which is nothing to sneeze at.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the alternative, I'll check it out!

Comment: Just to be sure, `optuna` cannot be used in a scikit learn Pipeline right? If for example I want to execute features selection and then the search together for instance.

Comment: @giacrava Ask a new question detailling what you want. It probably can be done but it's a bit unclear what you're asking in such a short comment.

Comment: Thanks, it was just a quick thought to know it optuna can be included in scikit learn pipelines, I still have to get into that and in case I'll do!

Answer (score 0):

You can sample `n_iter` combinations yourself beforehand and perform a GridSearchCV over that random subgrid:

```py
import random

def sample_grid(full_grid, n_iter, random_state=None):
    """
    sklearn's ParameterSampler (which, e.g., RandomizedSearchCV uses)
    hits overflow error if grid is too large, so we roll our own by
    producing a list-of-dicts amenable to be used in a GridSearchCV.
    """
    random.seed(random_state)
    return [{param_name: [random.choice(param_possibilities)]
             for param_name, param_possibilities in full_grid.items()}
            for _ in range(n_iter)]


# Somewhere down the road...
param_grid = {...}

gs = GridSearchCV(model,
                  param_grid=sample_grid(param_grid, n_iter=1_000),
                  ...)
```